# Symfony KNP Snappy Bundle: PDF does not load css file

Tags: php, css, symfony, symfony-2.3, symfony-3.1

I'm using the knp-snappy-bundle to generate PDF's out of twig.

But my css files are not loading.

I tried it with `static url`, with `absolute url` and with only `asset url`, noting works, but these are the normal `css files` which I also use when display for example in my edit form. Here are the three options I tried in my `pdf.html.twig` file

```
  // STATIC DOES NOT WORK
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://localhost/test/boot.css">

 // ASSET DOES NOT WORK
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('test/boot.css') }}">


// ABSOLUTE DOES NOT WORK
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ absolute_url(asset('test/boot.css')) }}">
```

Always get this:  `Warning: Failed to load https://localhost/test/boot.css (ignore)`

Comment: Are you running Symfony with the PHP built-in server on a different port than 80/443 ?

Comment: No, I'm using 80/443

Comment: Try using absolute urls. Example: {{ absolute_url(asset('css/bootstrap.css')) }}

Answer (score 1):

I presume you are using `wkhtmltopdf`, in that case you need to use the absolute path to the css file. Not sure what the path is to your web folder, but something like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/var/www/html/Symfony/test/boot.css">
```

I had this same problem with `wkhtmltopdf` and had to hard code it like that.

Answer (score 1):

pdf.html.twig file do not extend with another file. Try this code, it works

```
<link href="{{ app.request.scheme ~'://' ~ app.request.httpHost ~ asset('test/boot.css') }}" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

As soon as we're in Symfony you could try in TWIG like the following

```
{% stylesheets
   'test/boot.css'
   filter='cssrewrite' %}
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}"/>
{% endstylesheets %}
```

Your css file should be reside in your Symfony application web/test directory. Check availability in browser

```
http://localhost/test/boot.css
```

Should work